# Why does this undefined error occur when storing the first number to a $_SESSION[] variable?

Tags: php

I'm making a mini shopping cart for my project. Im storing the number of items chosen by the user, I don't understand that when i add one to my session variable I always get this error on the first go
**Undefined index: cart_1 in D:\wamp\www\MiniCart\cart.php on line 100**
And when I add again or refresh the same page it works fine. Why could this error be coming up? I removed the `+=1` from the statement and it worked fine, apparently there is no syntax error too.

**Cart.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();

//The page where to jump to after adding/editing cart.
$page = 'mini_cart_index.php';

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cart");
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Error:".mysqli_connect_error();
    echo "<br/>";
} else {
    echo "Connected to SQL<br/>";
}

//==================================================
if(isset($_GET['add']))
{
    $obt=$_GET['add'];
    $quantity_limit = 'SELECT id,quantity FROM products WHERE id='.mysqli_real_escape_string($link,(int)$_GET['add']);

    $quantity = mysqli_query($link,$quantity_limit);

    while($quantity_row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($quantity))
    {
        if($quantity_row['quantity']!=$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']])
        {
            $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+='1';
        }
    }

    /*  
    echo 'id='.$obt.' '.'next<br/>';
    echo 'Now storing info into session variable and adding one<br/>';
    echo $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']];
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'info stored<br/>';
    */  
}

//***************************************************
function products()
{
    GLOBAL $link;

    $get ="SELECT id,name,description,price FROM products
    WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER by id ASC";

    if($result=mysqli_query($link,$get))
    {
        echo "Data Selected to be displayed<br/>";
    } else {
        echo "Error:".mysqli_error($link);
    }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0)
    {
        echo "There are no products to display!<br/>";
    } else {
        while($get_row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo '<hr/><br/>';  
            echo 'displaying data from database<br/>';
            echo '==================================';

            echo '<p>'.$get_row['name'].'<br/>'.
                $get_row['description'].'<br/>'.
                number_format($get_row['price'],2).
                '<a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'"> Add</a>'.'</p>';
            echo '<hr/><br/>';

        }
    }   
}

echo 'outside'.$_SESSION['cart_1'];
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Mini_cart_index.php**

```
<?php require 'cart.php';?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php products() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that...

```
$var['abc'] += 1
```

...is the same as

```
$var['abc'] = $var['abc'] + 1
```

So if you've got a clean session and `$var['abc']` doesn't exist, you're going to get a warning because you're trying to read a non-existant value in order to add 1 to it.

While it's true that `0 + 1 = 1`
...what's actually happening here is `undefined + 1 = 1 with a warning`.

As other answers have mentioned - to fix the issue, you can explicitly check that the array index exists before trying to increment it.

I'd do that with the ternary operator like this:

```
$key = 'card_' . $_GET['add'];
$_SESSION[$key] = (isset($_SESSION[$key]) ? $_SESSION[$key] : 0) + 1;
```

This is effectively saying

```
$val = ($val if it exists, otherwise 0) + 1;
```

Comment: Ok i got it done - 

code: 

`if(isset($_GET['add']))
    {
    $key = 'cart_' . $_GET['add'].'<br/>';
    echo $key; // this will make cart_1 and cart_2
 //$_SESSION[$key] = (isset($_SESSION[$key]) ? $_SESSION[$key] : 0) + 1;
     if(isset($_SESSION[$key]))
     { 
     
      $_SESSION[$key] = $_SESSION[$key]+1;
      echo 'Total # of items in bag: '.$_SESSION[$key];
     }
     else
     {
      $_SESSION[$key]=0;
     }
    }`

It does add the item too.

Comment: could you please tell me that what does this question mark exactly do here
`'<a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'"> Add</a>'.'</p>';`

and when I press the add on the first click it shows nothing as if empty and when i go back and press add again then it starts from '1'- why so? And thanks once again for your help

Answer (score 2):

That code is filled with SQL injection vulnerabilities, you should use PDO and `prepare` your statements.
PHP is warning you because it has to read the current value and add to it, but the first time you try to access it doesn't exist.

You could suppress the warning with:

```
@$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+='1';
```

A better way to do it though would be checking if it exists first

```
$name = 'cart_'.$_GET['add'];
if(isset($_SESSION[$name]) {
  $_SESSION[$name] = 1;
} else {
  $_SESSION[$name] += 1;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I don't see any sql injection vulnerabilities. Just the fact that he's not using prepared statements doens't mean he's vulnerable to sql injection. Can you provide a specific instance?

Answer (score 0):

Change your if statement to check if it's empty too:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']] = 1;
} elseif ($quantity_row['quantity'] != $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]) {
    $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']] += 1;
}
```

Comment: Why? Giving the code that they should use doesn't actually answer the question of why it's happening.